# Azure Table Storage Rest API

Tags: php, api, azure, azure-table-storage

How would one make a request with PHP?

Also how would one do the authorization and date requirement?

Everything on the internet as an example is outdated or using visualstudio to make the request or format it. I'm looking for pure PHP or a example for me to get started.

Please don't link something from like 2013 cause it won't work

I already know there is a PHP for Azure Table Storage, but I want to use the API as I will only be querying data not inserting or updating

This is my request right now

```
 GET /Data2()?filter=Username%20eq%20'{username}' HTTP/1.1
Host: {tablename}.table.core.windows.net
Authorization: SharedKey {accountname}:{accountkey}
x-ms-date: 2016-09-16T00:31:08Z
Content-Type: application/json;odata=nometadata
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

and i get this response

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <code>AuthenticationFailed</code>
    <message xml:lang="en-US">Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:bf8eea79-0002-0107-15b1-0fad02000000
Time:2016-09-16T00:31:13.7387356Z</message>
</error>
```

Comment: For starters, you can't pass your storage account in your authorization header. You need to calculate authorization header value based on your request. Please take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx to see how authorization header is calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gaurav is correct, you need to generate the signature and set in the `Authorization` header in the format `Authorization:SharedKey {storage_account}:{signature}` for the Rest request. You can refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Constructing_Element for more details.

And Here is a code snippet in PHP for your information:

```
const AZURE_ACC_NAME = {storage_account};
const AZURE_PRIMARY_KEY = {storage_key};
const AZURE_TABLE = {table_name};

$date = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T',time());
$StringToSign = 'GET' . "\n" . 
            ''. "\n" . //Content-MD5
            '' . "\n" . //Content-Type
            $date. "\n" .
           '/'.AZURE_ACC_NAME.'/'.AZURE_TABLE.'()';
echo $StringToSign;
$sig = base64_encode(
    hash_hmac('sha256', urldecode($StringToSign), base64_decode(AZURE_PRIMARY_KEY), true)
);

$endpoint = 'https://'.AZURE_ACC_NAME.'.table.core.windows.net';
$url = $endpoint.'/'.AZURE_TABLE.'()';

$headers = [
    "x-ms-date:{$date}",
    'x-ms-version:2014-02-14',
    'Accept:application/json;odata=nometadata',
    "Authorization:SharedKey ".AZURE_ACC_NAME.":{$sig}"
];
var_dump($headers);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response  = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Do you know how I would do a filter? So filtering a ParititonKey or in my case filtering a property so find Username eq 'user'